# What is wrong with this program? Says a and b are not in the scope

Tags: c++

Compiler says that a and b is not declared in the scope:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class sample {
    private:
        int a, b;
    public:
        void setvalue() {
            a=25; b=40;`enter code here`
        }
    friend int sum(sample s1); //says a and b are not in the scope
};

int sum(sample s1) {
    return a+b; //says a and b are not in the scope
}

int main() {
    sample x;
    x.setvalue(); 
    cout<<"\nSum ="<<sum(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looking past the horrible editing (please fix it), it looks like you're trying to access `a` and `b` in a global function (`sum`). *Whose* `a` and `b` are you trying to use? You'll need an instance of `sample`. Did you mean to use `s1.a`, etc?

Comment: Expect multiple downvotes until you fix the code, which is currently nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
return a+b;
```

to

```
return s1.a+s1.b;
```

Comment: Why don't define sum inside the class?

Comment: Because then it will no longer be a free function, and I suppose OP want a free function.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `a` and `b` are members of the class `sample`. This means those variables must be accessed as part of an existing instance of `sample` using the `.` operator:

```
return a + b; // Tries to find variables named 'a' and 'b', but fails (error)
return s1.a + s1.b; // Uses the members of s1, finds them, and works correctly
```

However within a member function of a class, there is no need to use 's1' - the variables are already in scope as they are in the same scope as the function (class scope). So you could rewrite the class:

Add the following to the class, under public:

```
int sum()
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And in the main:

```
cout << "\nSum" << x.sum();
```

Comment: and i think sum(x) is the correct one..for x.sum() compiler gives the error

Comment: @Nareshjungshahi I meant that if you added the function I wrote to the class then `x.sum()` would work. BTW please mark as answer if it works.